# Thinking Sphinx - undefined method `klass'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, associations, rake, thinking-sphinx

I have an `Artwork` model that is associated to the models `Subject`, `Location`, `Keyword`, `Style`, and `Medium` by HABTM. I also have an association to an `Artist` model with one-to-many. Here's my error I keep getting:

```
>rake ts:index
Generating configuration to /Users/<user>/Developer/jtodd/jtoddgalleries/config/development.sphinx.conf
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's my indices file:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :artwork, :with => :active_record do
    indexes title, :sortable => true
    has jtg
    has width
    has height


    has subject.id, :as => :subject_ids
    has location.id, :as => :location_ids
    has keyword.id, :as => :keyword_ids
    has artist.first_name, :as => :artist_first
    has artist.last_name, :as => :artist_last

    has style.id, :as => :style_ids
    has medium.id, :as => :medium_ids
end
```

I can't figure out why I keep getting different errors. I may not have a firm grasp on fields vs. attributes and maybe that's where I'm going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming your associations are all listed in your Artwork model with plural names? It needs to be the same in your index definition.

As for fields vs attributes, a good rule of thumb is that anything you expect a user to type in and get results for should be a field. So, I'm guessing you'd want artist first and last names as fields.

Thus, an amended index definition:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :artwork, :with => :active_record do
  indexes title, :sortable => true
  indexes artist.first_name, :as => :artist_first
  indexes artist.last_name,  :as => :artist_last
  has jtg
  has width
  has height

  has subjects.id, :as => :subject_ids
  has locations.id, :as => :location_ids
  has keywords.id, :as => :keyword_ids
  has styles.id, :as => :style_ids
  has mediums.id, :as => :medium_ids
  # or is it media?
end
```

If you're still getting an error, can you run `rake ts:index --trace` and share the backtrace with us? :)

Comment: figured it out but this was exactly the problem, thank you for confirming!